# Use FullCalendar event sources to display an indeterminate number of calendars and their corresponding events

Tags: javascript, ruby, events, fullcalendar

FullCalendar has documentation around using eventSources to list multiple event on a single calendar ... I need this to be more dynamic so i pass `eventSources` my function that returns an array of calendars

```
function() {
  return $('#calendar').fullCalendar
  ({googleCalendarApiKey: '<YOUR API KEY>',
    eventSources:
      function(){
        getEventSources();
      }
    }
  );
};
```

I want to list every event from each calendar belonging to a user as opposed to a set number of calendars that I pass in.

Here's a function I created to do this.

```
function getEventSources(){
  const calendarList = "<%= @calendar_list %>"
  const keyArray = calendarList.map(cal => {
  return 'googleCalendarId'
  })

  const calendarIds = calendarList.map(cal => {
  return cal["id"]
  })

  eventSources = []

  for(i=0; i < keyArray.length; i++) {
    var obj = {}
    obj[keyArray[i]] = calendarIds[i]
    eventSources.push(obj);
  }
  return eventSources
};
```

calendarList is a list of calendars; it is defined in a controller, however I dont think I'm setting it correctly here... i've also tried setting using ajax and even passing it a json route.

I hand tested this and it worked, but I still cant get the calendar to load 
**2 main questions:** 
 1. am I passing my function to `eventSources` correctly in the eventCalendar function?
 2. whats the best way to declare `calendarList` for my use case?

Comment: Are you asking how to re-write that Ruby snippet in Javascript? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: yes...basically.. or even if there's already a solution for this problem, I don't want to pigeonhole myslef into thinking this is the only solution.

Comment: @ADyson, I've updated my question to contain my attempt at solving this using javascript, can you provide some help?

Comment: posted another update...this time i hand tested this and it should work but still doesnt

Comment: I can't see what `<%= @calendar_list %>` generates - can you show me? You should be able to use the View Source feature in your browser to check what the final rendered Javascript looks like. But I have noticed that you're putting it inside quote marks, so to Javascript it'll be a string instead of an object or array - and therefore functions such as ".map()" will not work as expected.